# Laravel 4 return messages

Tags: laravel, message, laravel-blade

Apologies Laravel newbee - on the learning curve.

In my controller I have

```
return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
                ->with('message', 'something went wrong');
```

How do I display  this in my blade template? Are these known as 'flash messages'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is known as a redirect with flash data.

```
 return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
            ->with('message', 'something went wrong');
```

*With* method flashes data to the session, you can retrieve it using Session::get in your View

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert-box success">
        <h2>{{ Session::get('message') }}</h2>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
@if ( Session::has('message') )
      <p class="alert">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
@endif
```

on the header of my base.blade.php